# Python encrypt using external program

Tags: python, encryption

Is there a program that will allow python in some way to encrypt/decrypt a file? Ideally, the code would call this program on the file and that file would then handle all the taking of the password, etc. The file would then be decrypted to a set location and deleted by the python after use.

Why do I want an external program? Because anything written in Python is too easy to reverse engineer. If there is no encryption done by the code itself, it would be much harder for your 'unwanted viewer' to access what is in that file.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the code can be reverse engineered; if your encryption can be broken just by reverse-engineering the code, then the algorithm was worthless to begin with.  Read about [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Comment: Reverse engineer? You are confused.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that my project will be compiled using 'pyinstaller'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of python's facility to call external programmes via the subprocess module. Then any encryption programme of your choice will do, provided that it allows command-line usage, like gpg.